# List of preferences for four ladies and four gentleman where no one obtains his or her first pick.

Tags: combinatorics

How can I determine a list of preferences for four ladies and four gentlemen where no one obtains his or her first choice in a stable matching determined by the Gale-Shapely algorithm, regardless of who proposes.

I understand how to use the Gale-Shapely algorithm, but not sure how do this.  Have tried using brute force but have not gotten very far.  I can't seem to make it so the 4th boy does not receive his 1st choice when they are proposing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you confirm this:

women are 1-4; men a-d; x can be anyone not already in that preference.

[ \begin{array}{lcr}
\mbox{1} & a&b&c&d \\
\mbox{2} & d & c&a&b \\
\mbox{3} & b & d&x&x \\
\mbox{4} & b & a&x&x \\
\ \\
\mbox{a} & 2 & 4&3&1 \\
\mbox{b} & 2 & 1&3&4 \\
\mbox{c} & 1 & 2&x&x \\
\mbox{d} & 1 & 3&4&2 \end{array}]

Men Propose:

step 1: 1 accepts c, rejects d. 2 accepts a, rejects b.

step 2: 1 accepts b, rejects c. 3 accepts d.

step 3: 2 accepts c, rejects a. 4 accepts a.

Women Propose:

step 1: a accepts 1. b accepts 3, rejects 4. d accepts 2.

step 2: a accepts 4, rejects 1.

step 3: b accepts 1, rejects 3.

step 4: d accepts 3, rejects 2. c accepts 2.

Comment: I missed the statement "regardless of who proposes" as I am misogynist.  (ok it was an honest oversight).

Comment: Ok, it might work now in both directions

Comment: If women propose to men, then 2 would end up with d in this case which is her first choice.

Comment: I get that 2 gets c if women propose to men. d gets 3.  In the last step 3 (having been rejected by b for 1) proposes to d who pick 3 in favor of 2.  2 then picks c.  Either way everyone gets their second pick.

Comment: my mistake you are right I think that will work both ways.

Comment: I checked this by hand, so I could be wrong, but it seems to me that the **only** stable matching here is the one that matches everyone with his/her 2nd choice, namely 1b,2c,3d,4a. In other words, there is **no** stable matching that matches anyone with his/her first choice, regardless of whether the Gale-Shapley algorithm is used or not.

Comment: @bof Then you could post this as the solution to another one of his questions that asked to show that there is at least two stable matchs for any set of preferences. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564531/prove-that-there-exist-at-least-two-stable-matches-between-the-men-and-the-women

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with that other question, which asks to show that there are at least two stable matchings, not for **any** set of preferences, but for preferences satisfying a certain hypothesis.