# Prove that there exist at least two stable matches between the men and the women.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

Suppose that more than one woman receives her lowest-ranked choice when the men propose.  How do you prove that there exist at least two stable matches between the men and the women?

Comment: Is all of this homework?

Answer (score 0):

As it is impossible for the proposer to end up with two that have their lowest preferences, the male proposal and female proposal solutions must be different but both still stable.  There must, therefore, be at least two stable pairings reflecting these two methods.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more on why the male proposal and female proposal solutions must be different but still stable based on the previous step? Thank you.

Comment: Alice prefers Adam to Bob.  Betty prefers Bob to Adam. Adam prefers Betty to Alice. Bob prefers Alice to Betty.  No other people are relevant to this but lets pretend they hate these 4 people more than anyone in the world.  This simplifies things.   If Adam and Bob propose, Adam will propose to Betty before Alice and Bob will propose to Alice before Betty. This makes the AB and BA case possible.  If the women propose,  Alice will not reject Adam to get Bob and Betty will not reject Bob to get Adam.  They will only allow the AA and BB case to occur unless they can find a better one.